# setOnClickListener throws NullPointerException

Tags: android, nullpointerexception

I'm calling an onClickListener on a button. I've done this a several times and it has worked before. But somehow it throws a `NullPointerException` this time. I've looked into multiple posts, but I still didn't get it.

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

  setContentView(R.layout.search);

  Button viewRequests = (Button) findViewById(R.id.view_requests);

    viewRequests.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() { // NPException occurred here

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        System.out.println("View request is clicked");

    }
});
 }
```

resource file:

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingLeft="20dp"
    android:paddingRight="20dp"
    android:paddingTop="10dp"
    android:paddingBottom="10dp" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/view_requests"
        android:background="@drawable/my_button"
        android:layout_width="120dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:paddingTop="3dp"
        android:paddingBottom="3dp"
        android:textSize="10sp"

        android:text="View Work Requests" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**EDIT**

LogCat

```
07-20 17:26:40.411: D/AndroidRuntime(334): Shutting down VM
07-20 17:26:40.411: W/dalvikvm(334): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception  (group=0x40015560)
07-20 17:26:40.431: E/AndroidRuntime(334): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-20 17:26:40.431: E/AndroidRuntime(334): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.rxprojects/com.rxprojects.activities.SearchActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
07-20 17:26:40.431: E/AndroidRuntime(334):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1647)
07-20 17:26:40.431: E/AndroidRuntime(334):  at android.app.ActivityThread.startActivityNow(ActivityThread.java:1487)
07-20 17:26:40.431: E/AndroidRuntime(334):  at android.app.LocalActivityManager.moveToState(LocalActivityManager.java:127)
07-20 17:26:40.431: E/AndroidRuntime(334):  at android.app.LocalActivityManager.startActivity(LocalActivityManager.java:339)
07-20 17:26:40.431: E/AndroidRuntime(334):  at android.widget.TabHost$IntentContentStrategy.getContentView(TabHost.java:654)
07-20 17:26:40.431: E/AndroidRuntime(334):  at android.widget.TabHost.setCurrentTab(TabHost.java:326)
07-20 17:26:40.431: E/AndroidRuntime(334):  at android.widget.TabHost$2.onTabSelectionChanged(TabHost.java:132)
07-20 17:26:40.431: E/AndroidRuntime(334):  at android.widget.TabWidget$TabClickListener.onClick(TabWidget.java:456)
07-20 17:26:40.431: E/AndroidRuntime(334):  at   android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2485)
07-20 17:26:40.431: E/AndroidRuntime(334):  at   android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:9080)
07-20 17:26:40.431: E/AndroidRuntime(334):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
07-20 17:26:40.431: E/AndroidRuntime(334):  at  android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
07-20 17:26:40.431: E/AndroidRuntime(334):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
07-20 17:26:40.431: E/AndroidRuntime(334):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
07-20 17:26:40.431: E/AndroidRuntime(334):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-20 17:26:40.431: E/AndroidRuntime(334):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
07-20 17:26:40.431: E/AndroidRuntime(334):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
07-20 17:26:40.431: E/AndroidRuntime(334):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
07-20 17:26:40.431: E/AndroidRuntime(334):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
07-20 17:26:40.431: E/AndroidRuntime(334): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
07-20 17:26:40.431: E/AndroidRuntime(334):  at   com.rxprojects.activities.SearchActivity.onCreate(SearchActivity.java:226)
07-20 17:26:40.431: E/AndroidRuntime(334):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
07-20 17:26:40.431: E/AndroidRuntime(334):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1611)
07-20 17:26:40.431: E/AndroidRuntime(334):  ... 18 more
```

Comment: çan you post the exact error message?

Comment: if you remove the click listener is the button shown on the screen? Also just to clarify is the layout xml file that you posted called `search.xml` and located in your `/res/layout/` folder?

Comment: Strange. Any suspicious logs? Try clean and re-build.

Comment: check your layout file is it right ?

Comment: @Tim Well the button is in the layout. It's always shown on the screen.

Comment: so if you remove the click listener you see the button on the screen and get no exceptions correct?

Comment: This may not be what you want, but for most buttons, I've been using android:onClick="buttonOnClickHandler" and coding public void buttonOnClickHandler(View v) {do what ever} in the activity that does the setContentView for the XML containing the button. You don't need to do a findViewById on the button, but you will get an error if you don't code the click handler or misspell it. I like it because there's no hassle with listeners or findViewById, just code a function in the activity that is using the button.

Comment: @Tim Yes. I've posted the log cat

Comment: Seems like a fluke to me then try cleaning your project to see if it corrects itself. If not perhaps try removing the drawable item `my_button` and leaving the button on the default background. I've seen some very strange errors before as result of corrupted drawable files (especially if it is a 9-patch)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the layout file you are passing is actually `R.layout.search`, clean and rebuild the project.

Comment: Oh, you're right. The button is in the inflated layout file. How do I setOnClickListener to that?

Comment: I've inflated a new layout `quick_search` which has the button onto `search`. How do I setOnClickListener to elements in `quick_search`?

Comment: you were actually doing well. You can only inflate views within an **already** inflated layout. That's why I told you that, if your layout actually contains that button with that id, then it could have been something related to "broken" R.java file. Just a clean an build project and that should have solved it. Otherwise, try what Tim told you in a direct comment to your question

Answer (score 2):

Check if you have more than one copy of `search.xml` in your project.  Perhaps you have separate versions for portrait/landscape, or versions specific to different screen sizes.  If you do, all versions must have the `android:id="@+id/view_requests"` attribute set on on the Button.

Comment: I've only one copy. Thanks for the heads up though.

Comment: I had the same issue. But when I remove portrait from the AndroidManifest.xml problem solved.

Answer (score 0):

Check whether you have the same id for Button in .xml fime and your .java file.